# swift locationManager clear region cache

Tags: ios, swift

i have an App that does actions on didEnterRegion and didExitRegion of CLBeaconRegions. Those are both on my viewcontroller class. Now the user should be able to set the UUID by himself. Therefor I made a second view controller (setibeaconVC) to change the string of the UUID.

It does work however the regions increase overtime the user changes the UUID in the App. So the Actions are called first one time after changing the UUID once the actions are called two times and so on.

Is there any command to clear the cache of those regions before I change the UUID?

Here´s part of my code.

ViewController:

```
var ibeaconuuid:String! = "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var beaconUUID:NSUUID!
var region:CLBeaconRegion!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    beaconUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: ibeaconuuid)
    region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconUUID, identifier: "Beacon")

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    region.notifyOnEntry = true
    region.notifyOnExit = true

    region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = false


    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways) {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }


    if (CLLocationManager .isMonitoringAvailableForClass(CLBeaconRegion))
    {
        print("OK")
    }
    else {
        print("Problem")

    }

    locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
    locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

And here the setiBeaconVC:

```
class setibeaconVC: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var ibeaconuuidtext: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let DestViewController: ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
    DestViewController.ibeaconuuid = ibeaconuuidtext.text!
}
```

}

Many Thanks
Stephan

Comment: You can loop over the `monitoredRegions` property of `CLLocationManager` and call `stopMonitoringRegion` for the current regions before starting monitoring of your new region

Comment: That´s a good idea. I thought that would work like this in swift: `for region in locationManager.monitoredRegions.allObjects as [CLBeaconRegion] {
            locationManager.stopMonitoringForRegion(region)
        }` however i get _value CLRegion has no member AllObjects_

Comment: yes, something like that

Comment: Just tried      `for region in locationManager.monitoredRegions {
            locationManager.stopMonitoringForRegion(region)
        }` that also does not work. If I print the monitoredRegions I always get only one. But did enterregion get´s called as often as i change the UUID.

Comment: You are always using the same region identifier, so even without removing the old beacon regions, you will be replacing it when you add then new one.   How are you returning to your first view controller after you enter the new region?  If you are pushing another instance of the first view controller then you will have multiple CLLocationManagers, and each will report the region entry.

Comment: Hi Paul, I´m returning to the first view controller with a normal segue. Basically my goal is that the user is able to change the UUID of the CLBeaconRegion. I tried a string in the same view controller but it gives me an error. It does not need to be on a second view controller.

Comment: That's what I suspected. You should use an unwind segue. You have multiple view controllers, each with their own location manager and delegate methods which is why you get multiple events firing

Comment: I see. That makes sense and explains it. However using unwind segue my String is not transferred with: `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let DestViewController: ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
        DestViewController.ibeaconuuid = ibeaconuuidtext.text!
    }` How can I transfer that string with unwind segue? Actually it does not need to be in a separate view controller. if there is an easier way to replace the CLBeaconRegion in the same view controller even better.

Comment: The unwind function you declare receives a UIStoryboardSegue as an argument. You can access the `sourceViewController` property of this segue which will be the view controller you are unwinding from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

Comment: I could fix it within the same view controller. I always tried to just replace the UUID String. They way to do it was stopMonitoringForRegion and set up a new region. Thanks for everybody´s help.

Answer (score 0):

Before re-creating the `CLBeaconRegion` in your view controller call `locationManager.stopMonitoringForRegion(region)`.

You will need to check this contains a region before calling as on first run it won't. Easiest way to do this is to change region to an optional rather than forced unwrapped optional. Then check like this:

```
var region:CLBeaconRegion? // Update to this.

if let r = region {
    locationManager.stopMonitoringForRegion(r)
}
```

Comment: Hi Gerard, I actually already tried "locationManager.stopMonitoringForRegion(region)". It´s called every time i segue to setibeaconVC. I also put in a button for force stop monitoring. It only leads to sop monitoring. When I activate it again the actions at didenterregion are called several times.

Comment: If I change CLBeaconRegion! to CLBeaconRegion? nothing get´s called at didenterregion.

Comment: Did you unwrap the CLBeaconRegion before passing it to startMonitoringForRegion? Should warn you... Update the question with your new code.